# Is it safe to access properties of `contentWindow`?

Tags: security, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox add-on. Part of the extension requires evaluating code in the context of a particular content window.

I found `tab_utils.getTabContentWindow`, which returns the ContentWindow of the given tab. The properties of this object are the properties of the webpage's `window` object.

From my testing it seems like accessing properties, calling ContentWindow functions, etc. all happens in the context of the webpage rather than the add-on. However, I'm not well-versed enough to know if this is sufficient for security, and the Mozilla docs don't make this clear.

Is it safe to access ContentWindow properties, use functions defined on ContentWindow, and access their results?

Answer (score 1):

Good q, answer is no. As with e10s coming out next version it will be a separate process. So it will use a shim. And that shim will be going away 6 months after e10s (process tabs) release.

So you're going to want to use the sdk contentScript. Looks like you're using sdk.

Comment: Here's a link to the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) on MDN.